# Sysprep - change computer name and SID's only

Tags: windows-embedded-7

Is it possible to sysprep in such as way that it only changes the SID's and prompts for a new computer name? The few times I've tried it's messed with user accounts, auto-login stuff, drivers and network settings.

Comment: Hi Chris - when you run sysprep, do you per chance use an answerfile or are you just running the sysprep gui..? Also, what happens with your accounts, drivers and network settings..?

Comment: Yeah I do. Probably not with the right content though, not quite sure what settings I'm supposed to use in this case. My accounts/drivers/network settings are all reset to their defaults.

Comment: Hi Chris - Not knowing how the image and answerfile was created initially, i recommend that you dload the ICE tool for Windows 7 Embedded from Microsoft. When you have it installed, load the answerfile currently being used and have ice validate it for correctness. Ice dowload link is http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11887 - when pressing download select only the files with toolkit in the name (8 files). Within the ICE environment you can specify the default settings such as local user accounts, network settings and drivers for non-natively supported devices.